# Proving that two measures are equal

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ be the lebesgue measure on  $\mathbb{R}$, Let $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the system of lebesgue measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $t>0$.

Show that $\mu: \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to [0,\infty], \mu(A):=t^{-n}\lambda(tA)$ defines a measure and that $\lambda(A)=\mu(A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

My work:

We have:$$\mu(\emptyset)=t^{-n}\cdot \lambda(t\cdot \emptyset)=t^{-n}\cdot \lambda(\emptyset)=t^{-n}\cdot 0=0 \quad \checkmark$$ and $$\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=t^{-n}\lambda \left(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}tA_n\right)\\ =t^{-n}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda(tA_n)=t^{-n}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}t^n\cdot t^{-n}\lambda(tA_n) =t^{-n}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}t^n\mu(A_n)$$  Hence:$$\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n) \quad \checkmark  $$

All in all, $\mu$ is a measure. But how can I show the second part, namely that $\lambda(A)=\mu(A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Monotone class theorem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have heard of monotone classes but never researched any further.

Comment: Well, the identity that you are dealing with must be reminiscent of dilating a rectangle by $t,$ the area gets $t^n$ because of dimension. Monotone class theorem or $\pi-\lambda$ systems let you show that it suffices to check in a generating set of a $\sigma$ algebra.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't mind if you write down how you'd prove it. I could do some research to understand your answer.

Comment: It may help to say what textbook you are studying from. Most measure theory textbooks will contain a theorem (derived using Monotone class theorem, Dykin $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, or otherwise) that gives conditions for two measures to by identical. All the theorems tell you (as a corollary) that to check that a given measure is equal to the Lebesgue measure, it suffices to check equality on rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lebesgue measure is defined by the restriction of the lebesgue outer measure to lebesgue measurable sets. The outer measure is defined by

$$ \lambda^*(A) = \inf \{ \sum_{j} \text{Vol} (I_j)  \; \vert  \; A \subset \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N} I_j \}$$

where the $I_j$'s are compact rectangles which cover $A$.

Let $A$ be a lebesgue measurable set and $t > 0$. We start by showing that $tA$ is lebesgue measurable. To do this we establish the fact that
$$ \lambda^*(tA) = t^n \lambda^*(A) $$

This follows by definition of the outer measure

\begin{align*}
\lambda^*(tA) &= \inf \{ \sum_{j} \text{Vol} (I_j)  \; \vert  \; tA \subset \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N} I_j \} \\
&= \inf \{ \sum_{j} \text{Vol} (I_j)  \; \vert  \; A \subset \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{t}I_j \} \\
&= \inf \{ t^n \sum_{j} t^{-n}\text{Vol} (I_j)  \; \vert  \; A \subset \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{t}I_j \} \\
&= \inf \{ t^n \sum_{j}\text{Vol} (\frac 1 tI_j)  \; \vert  \; A \subset \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{t}I_j \} \\
&= t^n \inf \{\sum_{j}\text{Vol} (\frac 1 tI_j)  \; \vert  \; A \subset \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{t}I_j \} \\
&= t^n \inf \{\sum_{j}\text{Vol} (\tilde{I}_j)  \; \vert  \; A \subset \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N} \tilde{I}_j\} \\
&= t^n \lambda^*(A).
\end{align*}

We now show that $tA$ is lebesgue measurable if $A$ is measurable. By definition we must show that for any $E \subset \mathbb R^n$

$$ \lambda^*(E) = \lambda^*(E \cap tA) + \lambda^*(E \cap (tA)^c)$$

Since $(tA)^c = tA^c$ we have

\begin{align*}
\lambda^*(E \cap tA) + \lambda^*(E \cap (tA)^c) &= \lambda^*(E \cap tA) + \lambda^*(E \cap tA^c) \\
&= \lambda^*(t \frac 1 t E \cap tA) + \lambda^*(t \frac 1 t E \cap tA^c) \\
&= \lambda^*\big( t  (\frac 1 t E \cap A) \big) + \lambda^*\big( t(\frac 1 t E \cap A^c)\big) \\
&= t^n \lambda^*( \frac 1 t E \cap A) + t^n \lambda^*(\frac 1 t E \cap A^c)\\
&= t^n \big( \lambda^*( \frac 1 t E \cap A) + \lambda^*(\frac 1 t E \cap A^c)\big) \\
&= t^n \lambda^*(\frac 1 t E) = \lambda^*(E).
 \end{align*}

Therefore $tA$ is Lebesgue measurable. Since $tA$ and $A$ are both Lebesgue measurable we have by definition that

$$ \lambda^*(tA) = \lambda(tA) \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda^*(A) = \lambda(A)$$

Hence $ \lambda(tA) = t^n \lambda(A)$ which is equivalent to  $\lambda(A) = \mu(A)$.

Comment: How'd you know that $tA$ is lebesgue mesurable? Thank you very much, very clean!

Comment: @Analysis see my edit.

Comment: Brilliant explanation.